# Why my program is not changing values in struct variables?

Tags: c++

Well, i've typed this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct workers
{
   char workername[55];
   int workernumb;
   float workerwage;
};
void changewage(workers worker1);
void show(workers worker1);
int main() // Defines all the workers profile and then call 'void show' to show the selected worker profile, is working well.
{
   workers worker1=
   {
       "The name of the worker goes here",
        The number of the worker goes here,
        The wage of the worker goes here
    };
   cout << "Worker data:" << endl;
   show(worker1);
   changewage(worker1);
   cout << "New worker wage:" << endl;
   show(worker1);
   return 0;
}
void show(workers worker1) // Program that shows the workers profile, is also working fine.

{
   cout << "Name: " << worker1.workername << endl;
   cout << "Number: " << worker1.workernumb<< endl;
   cout << "Wage: " << worker1.workerwage<< endl;
}

void changewage(workers worker1) // Program that changes the wage of a selected worker, here it is not working fine.

{
    float newwage;
    cin >> newwage;
    newwage=worker1.workerwage;
}
```

It's meant to be used to show the workers profile and change his wage, when i type the new wage it should be changing the 'worker1.workerwage', making the units in 'void show' be also changed and then the new profile would show the new worker wage.
The problem is that it still showing the previous values, and not changing anything.
P.S: The program by itself is working fine, the only problem is that one of it's functions is not working in the way i wanted to. And also as you can see i'm a beginner in learning c++, so sorry if i did some mistakes...

Comment: Also, once you get over the pass by value, it should really be `worker1.workerwage = newwage;` - The assignment target is on the *left*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass by reference if you want to modify the object.

```
void changewage(workers& worker1) // Program that changes the wage of a selected worker, here it is not working fine.

{
    float newwage;
    cin >> newwage;
    worker1.workerwage = newwage; // another mistake was here
}
```

The reason your code is not working is because  worker1 is copied and you modify the copy, the copied object is local to the function and when the function returns the copied object dies.

Comment: Wow, I didn't knew about that!
 Now that i changed it on the program it is working in the way i needed, thank you!